# Fail to deploy application to appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

> Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy 
>     failed: Validation Error: Java App Engine components not installed. 
>     Fix by running 'gcloud components install app-engine-java' on command-line.

I already install the latest app-engine-java and google cloud SDK 
And i also reinstalled cloud Sdk, that is not working for me.

below is my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
 <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.2</version>
 <configuration>
   <stage.enableJarSplitting>true</stage.enableJarSplitting>
   <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>
   <cloudSdkPath>/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk</cloudSdkPath>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use Java and App Engine I recommend you to take a look to this official  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/environment-setup) in order to install the required SDK and configure your develop  environment with the necessary tools for the purpose of deploy successfully your app.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: doing the same still visualizing the same thing